# Django query to dict with corresponding values

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-database

I'm working on a shop project and want to be able to see what most sold products on my shop are.

Here is my `models.py`

```
class Product(models.Model):
    #some values like name, price, etc...

class Purchase(models.Model):
    purchase_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # This is the only important field for this model regarding the problem that I Have
    # Other fields include stuff like buyers info, end price, etc...


class PurchaseContains(models.Model):
    #Every product has its amount, purchase its related to and the product of course, with some other values as well, but not related to the problem I'm having 
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product...) 
    purchase = models.ForeignKey(Purchase...)
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
```

Now what I want is to do a query thats going to give me what `Products` from `PurchaseContains` are bought the most (by `amount` from the table) and also the `Purchase` itself must be completed (`purchase_completed==True` in `Purchase` for the given product in `PurchaseContains`)

Now this is what I have done:

```
sold_the_most= PurchaseContains.objects.filter(purchase__purchase_completed=True).values("product", 'amount')
sold_the_most_dict= {}
for i in sold_the_most:
    sold_the_most_dict[i["product"]] = sold_the_most_dict.get(i['product'], 0)+i["amount"]
```

As you can see I get the `products` and `amount` for purchases that are completed and then do the loop for it to get them in the dictionary.

Now this does work and it gives me the output that I can work with, but I'm sure that there is a better solution for it. Some query that can maybe give me the data in the form  that looks something like `[[product, amount], [product, amount], ...]` (not expecting it like this straight away, but you get the point).

I have searched for a long time and the solution that you see is the best I came up with, because I'm not too familiar with Django queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you want something like a `GROUP_BY` in SQL. It is possible to do that in Django using [aggregation features of the ORM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/#topics-db-aggregation):

```
from django.db.models import Sum

values = PurchaseContains.objects.filter(purchase__purchase_completed=True).values("product").annotate(total=Sum("amount")).values('product','total')
print(values)
```

Comment: Follow up question if you don't mind. Is the "total" you put there some reserved word or something, because when I put other names in there I either get an error or a wrong results are given(for "amount it gives wrong amount values)

Comment: no it is not. but make sure you are annotating a variable with same name.